# avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "\.\COM(X)": Access is denied

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

I am working on Arduino Lilypad and cannot fix this problem since long time.
Any solution for this problem_???

```
     avrdude: Version 6.3-20171130
     Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
     Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

     System wide configuration file is "E:\Softwares\arduino-nightly\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf"

     Using Port                    : COM10
     Using Programmer              : arduino
     Overriding Baud Rate          : 57600
 avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "\\.\COM10": Access is denied.



 avrdude done.  Thank you.

 Problem uploading to board.  See 
 http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for suggestions.
```

Comment: Check the windows device manager if COM10 is the correct port and make sure that no other software is currently communicating on that port (maybe through a windows reboot).

Comment: I already tried it, I also tried changing the name of the port and using the port which is not in use But Still Not working...

Comment: Thanks a lot for all of your convenience but now I am solved with my problem on uploading the code in Lilypad all I have done is just unplugged all the connections of my hardware and then uploaded the code and then I connected my hardware connections and I am Done with it

Answer (score 0):

1. Start Device Manager. Does it show the Arduino on COM10? If not, make sure you've installed the CH340 driver for Chinese knockoffs.
2. Go to Tools -> Board -> Arduino/Genuino Uno

If the above hasn't worked, I'm sure the company you ordered it from would be willing to give you another.

Answer (score 0):

i've seen that before and usually going to tools-port and clicking what shows up works, maybe your arduino is not connected to COM10